# How to fill metadata info for tvOS info panel when using Airplay?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, tvos, airplay

I'm barely new to iOS.

I'm able to reproduce streams(no local video) via AVPlayer using Airplay.
Also, MPNowPlayingInfo and RemoteCommandManager are supported, using external medatada, not included into the streams.
But, I would like to fill the info panel with title, artwork, etc. on AppleTv/tvOS.
[image]
The image is part of WWDC17 talk titled "[Now Playing and Remote   Commands on tvOS](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc17/251)".

My question is not about tvOS apps, which the referenced talk is about, but about a iOS app that plays video via Airplay.

My guess is that the played AVAsset needs to have medatada, which currently would be empty.
I've been checking AVMutableMetaDataItem, but still don't understand if that's what I would need to use, nor how to do it.

Does anyone has any hint?

Answer (score 0):

The WWDC 2019 Talk :( https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/503/ ) which is about Delivering Intuitive Media Playback with AVKit speaks about using the external metadata during Airplay and how they have provided the API for iOS now which is similar to what was present on tvOS. (Refer from duration of 7 minutes in the Video mentioned above where they explain the same.) Hope this helps:)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I had not yet seen that talk. I still need to test it for to confirm if that works with the now playing info on apple tv, not just on the ios widget.

Comment: I've not yet make this work *in airplay* even creating custom avplayeritem.externalmetadata (on iOS since 12.2). Panel Info is still empty. Maybe it's because I don't use AVPlayerViewController.

Comment: Setting externalMetadata on the AVPlayerItem allows the AVPlayerViewController to display the Info panel on the AppleTV app. But still not while AirPlaying...